# Как записать квадратные скобки как текст?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как можно изменить запрос, чтобы квадратные скобки учитывались как текст?
Нужно найти все процедуры, в которых использовалась таблица `[Users]`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype
FROM syscomments c
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%.[Users]%'
```

Comment: Но ведь можно же в процедурах записать имя таблицы и без этих скобок. И тогда ваш запрос не найдёт его.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте escape-символ:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype
FROM syscomments c
     INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%.#[Users#]%' ESCAPE '#'
```

[Использование escape-символа](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-the-escape-clause)

ЗЫ: Если таблица не использовалась в динамических запросах внутри процедур и речь идет об одной БД, то проще всего посмотреть в каких объектах используется таблица через зависимости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]